# Why do we say someone is "on their computer"?

Tags: expressions, prepositions, word-usage

We don't say they are *on* the tv when watching TV, and we don't say they are *on* the radio when listening to the radio. But if someone is, like me right now, using their computer, they are ON the computer.

I just find it a strange way of wording it. Is there a reason why the preposition *on* is collocated with computer?

Comment: Relevant: "[Preposition IN Vs Preposition ON when writing by an electronic device](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137687)" There is some speculation there about the origins of this expression, but no clearly sourced answer. But WS2's comment does mention the related and older usage "work things out 'on' a mechanical calculator." I'd note that we also say someone is "on the phone." So computers are not unique.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! It seems to me that your question is a little vague (you don't specify what you mean by the word "why"). If you want to know the historical origins, this is a good place to ask (and I hope people will soon be able to tell you the answer). However, if you are still learning English and want more practical guidance about how to figure out which preposition to use in which circumstances, this question would be a better fit on the site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). Can you please edit your post to clarify what you want to learn?

Comment: Hi sumelic. First time posting on the site after lurking for a while but I'm (obviously) not up to date with rules regards where certain posts go.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it clearer. If someone is watching Tv, they are watching TV. They're not ON the tv. If someone is listening to the radio, they're NOT on the radio. But if someone is, like me right now, using their computer, they are ON the computer.

Comment: Apologies btw. Hit enter too soon.

Comment: @sumelic Working out an answer was also accomplished ***on*** a slide rule. As a side note, *we* don't say that. Ones in our household are referred to as being ***at*** their computer(s) not atop them.

Comment: Just for the record, sumelic: English is my mother tongue (which doesn't sound right seeing as I'm Irish lol) so the ELL suggestion isn't needed. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @Sem75: OK then, sounds like this was indeed the right place to post your question. As I said, I hope you get a good answer! I haven't been able to find any information about this yet.

Comment: One could certainly say that they were ***on*** their computer when they are ***at*** their computer when connected to a network ***online***. And even then, most (wifi?) networks don't use "lines".

Comment: @Stan But you can be ON the computer even if you're not connected to the internet. I just find it a strange way of wording it.

Comment: It's what it's always been, going back to 70s, if not earlier.  Likely it's shortened from "*working* on the computer", the phrase that would have been used first.  (Back in the 60s it was more likely to be called "feeding the monster" or some such, as interaction was done via decks of cards and an operator.)

Comment: I suppose because unlike when watching TV, your hands are *on* the keyboard.

Comment: You're also _on_ the phone when talking to someone using a telephone. The main reason it wouldn't do to use _on_ with tv and radio is of course because it means something else there: someone who's on the telly is being shown in a programme, not watching from the couch. And as @DogLover says, at least with a computer, you are actually resting part of you on part of the appliance.

Comment: Had to read the question twice to realize you were referring to _the person listening to_ the radio or watching TV. At first glance I instantly thought "Why, of course people are ON the radio"...

Comment: Could/Should an answer also suit *on the PlayStation* or *on the Xbox*? They seem similar but not all suggestions so far work in those cases?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that there's a silent working there, and so the sentence is a contraction, as in:

> I'm (*working*) on my computer.